# Why there are 6T states in opcode fetch of call instruction of 8085 rather than 4,which are in general?

Tags: timing, microprocessors, 8085

I am learning 8085 architecture and its working.All instructions which I have been through had 4t-states in opcode fetch cycle.However,Call instruction had 6(totally 18,6+2*3(for writing current pc on stack,i assume)+2*3(for reading the address and storing in pc)).
can someone clarify the sequence of actions for call and change in t-state value of call?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there 6T states in opcode fetch of CALL instead of 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839962/why-are-there-6t-states-in-opcode-fetch-of-call-instead-of-4)